# Why my tableView is repeating the last object? PFQuery using pointer

Tags: swift, pointers, tableview, relation, pfquery

I want to list all favorite ServiceProviders from the current user. Everything is working right except the table view: its duplicating the last object.

There is a class Favorite: objectId, User (pointer to User), ServiceProvider (pointer to ServiceProvider).

```
func baseQuery() -> PFQuery {
    let favoriteQuery = PFQuery(className: "Favorite")
    favoriteQuery.whereKey("favoriteUser", equalTo:PFUser.currentUser()!)
    favoriteQuery.includeKey("favoriteServiceProvider")
    favoriteQuery.orderByDescending("createdAt")
    return favoriteQuery
}

override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery {
    return self.baseQuery().fromLocalDatastore()
}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return objects!.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject?) -> PFTableViewCell {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("favoriteCell") as! FavoriteTableViewCell!

    if cell == nil {
        cell = FavoriteTableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "favoriteCell")
    }

    print("Founded \(objects!.count) favorite(s) from subquery")
    //print(objects)

    for object in objects! {

        if let favoriteServiceProvider = object["favoriteServiceProvider"] as? PFObject {

            let varspName = favoriteServiceProvider["spName"] as? String
            print("spName: \(varspName)")
            cell.labelspName.text = varspName

            let varspCity = favoriteServiceProvider["spCity"] as? String
            print("spCity: \(varspCity)")
            cell.labelspCity.text = varspCity

            let pictureUser: PFFile = (favoriteServiceProvider["spUserPhoto"] as? PFFile)!
            print("spServiceProviderPhoto: \(pictureUser)")
            pictureUser.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (data: NSData?, err: NSError?) -> Void in
                if data != nil{

                    //Rounded spPhoto
                    cell.imageViewUserPhoto.image = UIImage(data: data!)
                    cell.imageViewUserPhoto.layer.cornerRadius = cell.imageViewUserPhoto.frame.size.width / 2
                    cell.imageViewUserPhoto.clipsToBounds = true
                    cell.imageViewUserPhoto.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor().CGColor
                    cell.imageViewUserPhoto.layer.borderWidth = 2

                }
            }

            let varRating = favoriteServiceProvider["spAverageRating"] as? Int
            print("spAverageRating: \(varRating)")
            cell.ratingControl.rating = varRating!

        }
    }

    return cell

}
```

I can found 2 favorites and it is ok!

And can see the 'prints' correctly.

```
spName: Optional("Service Provider Name")
spCity: Optional("Florianópolis / SC")
spServiceProviderPhoto: <PFFile: 0x12fde9de0>
spAverageRating: Optional(5)

spName: Optional("Service Provider Name 2")
spCity: Optional("Florianópolis / SC")
spServiceProviderPhoto: <PFFile: 0x12ff7ca60>
spAverageRating: Optional(4)
```

Everything looks like to be ok, but ... the app is repeating only the last object (showing two times the same object). What is wrong?

Comment: Why you loop thru your entire `objects` every time you create your cell? maybe this is the reason why you are getting same cell every time since they all end up with same last `object`. You need definitely need some `if` statement to pick the correct data for your current cell.

Answer (score 1):

You are looping through the `objects` collection for every cell. Therefore each cell gets populated with the last cell's values. Instead you should be indexing:

```
let object = objects[indexPath.row]
```

Also, `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` always returns a cell, so there is no need to check for nil.

Comment: Thank you very much. :-)

Comment: No worries. Do you want to accept the answer to close off the question then?